PowerBI Expression.Error: The column 'Column1' of the table wasn't found
I have this query in my powerBi
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://endpoint.com")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"payload", "metadata"}, {"payload", "metadata"}),
    #"Expanded metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "metadata", {"created_at", "updated_at", "_id", "error_details", "category", "form_id", "agent_id", "location", "prospect_id", "status"}, {"metadata.created_at", "metadata.updated_at", "metadata._id", "metadata.error_details", "metadata.category", "metadata.form_id", "metadata.agent_id", "metadata.location", "metadata.prospect_id", "metadata.status"}),
    #"Split Column" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded metadata", "metadata.status", each _, {"metadata.status.0"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column",{{"payload", type any}, {"metadata.created_at", type datetime}, {"metadata.updated_at", type datetime}, {"metadata._id", type text}, {"metadata.error_details", type any}, {"metadata.category", type text}, {"metadata.form_id", type text}, {"metadata.agent_id", type any}, {"metadata.location", type any}, {"metadata.prospect_id", type any}, {"metadata.status.0", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

but I get the error:
Expression.Error: The column 'Column1' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Column1

which is weird cause the same query bu with json, word fine like so:
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Incubtek-1\Downloads\data.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"payload", "metadata"}, {"payload", "metadata"}),
    #"Expanded metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "metadata", {"created_at", "updated_at", "_id", "error_details", "category", "form_id", "agent_id", "location", "prospect_id", "status"}, {"metadata.created_at", "metadata.updated_at", "metadata._id", "metadata.error_details", "metadata.category", "metadata.form_id", "metadata.agent_id", "metadata.location", "metadata.prospect_id", "metadata.status"}),
    #"Split Column" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded metadata", "metadata.status", each _, {"metadata.status.0"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column",{{"payload", type any}, {"metadata.created_at", type datetime}, {"metadata.updated_at", type datetime}, {"metadata._id", type text}, {"metadata.error_details", type any}, {"metadata.category", type text}, {"metadata.form_id", type text}, {"metadata.agent_id", type any}, {"metadata.location", type any}, {"metadata.prospect_id", type any}, {"metadata.status.0", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

can Anyone help?emphasized text
